# Allowing GET requests only from specified server IP

Tags: php, security, get, webserver, server-to-server

I want to update records in a database through an api.php. I do this by sending GET requests to the API on the server from another particular server.

I tried limiting CORS to only that specific server, but GET requests were still accepted from the browser. I also tried to set a condition to match the server's IP with the one specified in the API and abort if it's false. However, I fear that this is an imprudent move as I am not that experienced in these types of situations.

Can I safely limit the api to allow GET requests only from this specific server address?

**System architecture**

- **Webserver**: Nginx
- **App language**: php(5.3), javascript, html, css
- **Database**: Mysql

Comment: Aside: `GET` should not be used for updating a resource

Comment: You can. There are many scenarios of what you can do. Now, the issue is obviously - knowledge level. In my opinion, the best way to deal with these kinds of limits is on the web server (my personal choice is `nginx`), not in app language. You can opt in for IP restriction, you can choose to authenticate people based on username / password, bearer token, api key, public key and what not. I guess you can tell that your question is really broad. How about you start by expanding the question with web server software?

Comment: Using IP addresses for authorization or authentication purposes is always questionable. I suggest you take a look at client side certificates instead.

Answer (score 0):

An solution would be to use [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/).

> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

You can find the PHP framework to generate/check the tokens at https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework